# Android - BillingClient returns empty purchases list

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billingclient

Some of my users tell me that my app forgets the purchased subscriptions every now and then. It works for 3-4 days and then it forgets them. This is a very important issue as users might suspect fraud. I am using billing library 4.0.0 and I have implemented the billing logic as per Google's guidelines.

From what I have gathered it happens when for some reason the billing service connection is interrupted. (Play Store is updating for example)

I have managed to replicate this scenario the following way

```
- Disable internet connection
- Clearing Play Store app data
- Fresh launch of my app.
- Call billingClient.startConnection()
    onBillingSetupFinished called with responseCode BILLING_UNAVAILABLE
    user sees -> The app says "no subscription purchased"

- Enable internet connection
- re-initialize BillingClient.
    onBillingSetupFinished called with responseCode OK. billingClient.isReady() returns true. 
- Call billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync() and billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync().
    onSkuDetailsResponse is called with the skuDetailsList filled with all the proper data. However:
    onQueryPurchasesResponse is called with empty purchase list -> Again user sees "no subscriptions purchased"
```

**Important** If at this point I open Play Store it shows the purchased subscriptions. But the app still gets an empty purchases list.

If I keep calling `billingClient.startConnection()` or `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()` at some point after about 10 minutes one attempt will succeed and return a non empty purchases list.

Is it possible to tell Play Store to refresh its subscription data for my app? How can someone handle this scenario gracefully ?

Comment: You can try preserving the purchase state in local storage like `DataStore` or `EncryptedSharedPreferences`.

Comment: @DarShan Yes I thought about that and I might eventually do it if no better solution is found. But that is basically a hack to go around something that should be working properly and isn't.  The correct solution would be to have the billing logic work as it should relying only on BillingClient.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just handled it manually. When I successfully get purchases I save them locally with a timestamp. When I get a scenario where local purchases are not empty but the billing client returns an empty list, I trust the local data as long as they are not too old. By the time the local data "expires" the billing client should have returned to a working state. And I keep retrying to refresh purchases every 1 minute for 20 minutes max when that scenario is detected

Comment: Could be related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162703/google-play-billing-querypurchasesasync-querypurchasehistoryasync-return-empty

Comment: The same thing is happening with us, every now and then, someone is complaining that the purchase is no longer valid, after 2-3 months, even though we are acknowledging each purchase and doing everything correctly from our end. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @JazibKhan Not a proper one. As I wrote in my comment above I keep a local copy of purchases to bypass this issue. For more details read the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `acknowledgePurchase` for every purchase. 
See [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#acknowledgePurchase(com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener)) and [the article](https://medium.com/googleplaydev/working-with-google-play-billing-part-2-dde12b852e9b) for more details.

Comment: Yes I know, I am doing that. The billing flow is implemented as per Google's guidelines. The problem appears when for some reason Play  Store cannot respond with the correct data for some reason. After a few retries or some time passes it eventually returns the correct data. But that is a problem for the app and the users

Comment: @Anonymous have you fixed it?

Comment: @SujithSManjavana No, I did what I described in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me!

BillingClient billingClient = ...;

billingClient must be ready -> billingClient.isReady() == true;

So, always call billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(...) from

```
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                        queryProductDetails();
                        queryPurchases();
                    }
                }
```

when initialize the billingClient connection! Keep it up :)