# Google PLay Billing queryPurchasesAsync & queryPurchaseHistoryAsync return empty items when more than 1 user logged in in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-billing

does anyone know how to get active subscription when more than 1 user accounts are logged in in Play Store? I've followed the steps in the documentation, it works normal when only 1 user logged in in the Play Store

Here is what i've done

```
val billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).setListener(purchasesUpdateListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()

//Starting connection
billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
   override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
       queryPurchasesAsync()
       queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()
   }

   override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
       //Do something to reconnect
   }
})

fun queryPurchasesAsync(){
   billingClient?.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .build()
   ) { result, purchases ->
      //Process puchases data
      //Result is always ok
      //purchases always return empty when 2 users are logged in in the Play Store, but return list of active subscription when only 1 user logged in in the play store
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was struggling to figure out why my queryProducts was giving an empty list when I have the active subscription showing in the Play store app on same device... I removed all other accounts on the device and then it is working fine. This seems like a major bug in the Billing library

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the library that has been happening for a long time. I had the same issue with in-app purchases using the Billing library v6, and it was resolved when I cleared the data and cache of **Google Play Services** on the affected phone. I hope this helps someone.